# React-Hook Form: How do I convert the value of the quantity into a number that is inside the useFieldArray?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have already declared the `input` to only receive numbers:

```
  <input
              type="number"
              name={`order[${nestIndex}].variantion[${k}].qty`}
              ref={register({ required: true })}
              defaultValue={item.qty}
              style={{ marginRight: "25px" }}
            />
```

But this would still save as a string. How can I convert the value of the `quantity` into a number or if I could parse this into an integer?

**The quantity input field is in the nestedFieldArray**

```
export default ({ nestIndex, control, register }) => {
  const { fields, remove, append } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: `order[${nestIndex}].variation`
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {fields.map((item, k) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.id} style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
            <label>{k + 1}</label>

            <input
              type="number"
              name={`order[${nestIndex}].variantion[${k}].qty`}
              ref={register({ required: true })}
              defaultValue={item.qty}
              style={{ marginRight: "25px" }}
            />

            <Size
              name={`order[${nestIndex}].variantion[${k}].color`}
              menuItems={colorItems}
              refer={register({ required: true })}
              defaultValue={item.color}
              control={control}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I recreated this in: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-data-in-step-1-and-step-2-with-nestedarray-7hyksh?file=/src/nestedFieldArray.js:485-1532

This is what the data looks like in the console:

[image]

Comment: Use parseInt() => `var numberFive = parseInt('5')`

Comment: Do you need to use `react-hook-form@5`? Since v6 you can set `valueAsNumber` for `register`.

Comment: @knoefel if it's in v6, would I neet to change a lot of things with my codes?

Comment: @knoefel I tried to update it and set the `register` with `valueAsNumber: true`, I am getting this error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `Step2`.

Comment: Check the [migration guide](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v5-to-v6) to update from v5 to v6. But i would suggest if you have to update `react-hook-form` than just update to the current version v7.

Comment: @knoefel I'm already on the process of it. But I'm countering this error when I've updated everything on it. It says that `t.split is not a function` and points out to this error ` refer={register({ required: true })}`  - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-data-in-step-1-and-step-2-v6-30oryd?file=/src/fieldArray.js:914-951

Comment: `register` changed from v6 to v7 - you have to spread it now like this `{...register('name')}` -> [Migration Guide](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On handler submit you can change product qty into integer using **parseInt()** and push it into the new child array and after the all product detail convert it then you can push it into new parent array.

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const newOrder = [];
    data.order.forEach(({ product, variantion }) => {
      const newVariantion = [];
      variantion.forEach(({ qty, color }) => {
        newVariantion.push({ qty: parseInt(qty), color });
      });
      newOrder.push({ product, variantion: newVariantion });
    });

    action(newOrder);
    console.log(newOrder);

    push("/step2");
  };
```